# PDO how to escape string of an input regex

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to search something content special character and use execute($params) to escape string. A incorrect result is return. To ensure input is correct, I have try search by using phpmyadmin search function, a expected result is returned. Following is my sample code.

```
  $sql = "SELECT id,filter_value,description FROM filter_table WHERE filter_value LIKE ? ";
  $params = array('%.*\b(https:\/\/www\.deno\.com\/R\/keyword)\b.*(Sus"ρ"icious R)\b.*%');

  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES UTF8');
  $connection->exec("SET NAMES UTF8");
  $connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute($params);
  echo $statement->rowCount(); // Return 0, Expected result should be >= 1
```

filter_value is containing with blob data type.

Comment: *"I'm unable to get result that I expected"* - please elaborate what your expectation was and what the actual result was.

Comment: Expected result should be return more than 0. I added comment to the code.